# "Please think to send me your solution by next Friday. " Is it correct?

Tags: word-usage, formality, language-formation

I would like to ask my students to send me the solution of an assignment. The deadline is Friday.

Is it correct to write "Please think to send me your solution by next Friday." ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you mean "Please **remember** to send me your solution by next Friday. " *PS: assignments" rarely have "solutions"* (and it is "solution **to**)

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you very much!

Comment: If the deadline actually is Friday, then you are telling them, not asking a favor. The word *please* marks a favor you are asking - which you are not. A hybrid: use @Greybeard idea,  "The assignment deadline is Friday. Remember, it's due Friday."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the meanings of the two expressions are quite closely synonymous, unlike 'remember to [+V]', '[not] think to [+ V]' is what is called a *negative polarity item*; it is only found in questions and negative statements.

- *Did you think to congratulate Jill on her promotion?*
- *I didn't think to bring extra clothing.*

We'd never say, for instance,

- *I thought to take my umbrella ('remembered' works here, of course)

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/not-think-to-do-something) has examples of the negated form; it also has some false positives (thought = considered).

The usage is a bit starchy, especially the interrogative form.

...............

Not to be confused with What do you think to (= about taking) a walk along the cliff path?, 'think to [+ N]'.

Comment: Good point about usage of "think", but it doesn't seem appropriate for the OP's context even if it was in a negative statement. To "think" something suggests spontaneous ideation - to say "I didn't think to send in the solution" suggests that no one told you to do it, it just never crossed your mind in the first place. The better option here would be "I didn't remember to send in the solution" - someone else told you to send it in.

Comment: Nizar concurs with Greybeard's (and my) estimation of what is intended; 'think to' should be 
 'remember to'. And yes, there is not strict synonymity; 'think' certainly connotes whirring cogs to a greater degree than 'remember'. (Though I can't see how spontaneous ideation fits in with getting one's assignment in on time.)  But the different behaviours of 'think to' and 'remember to' are certainly pertinent here.